# Make visible all tooltips at the same time - MatTooltip Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, tooltip, viewchild

Is there any way to display all the tooltips at the **same time** in angular matTooltip. We can do this like below, but it needs to declare all the viewChild for doing that,

```
@ViewChild('tooltip', { static: true })tooltip:MatTooltip;
```

There are more than 50 mat-tooltip elements in the app. Is there are any easy way to do that in angular.

Answer (score 0):

There's [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

Something like

```
@ViewChildren(MatToolTip) tooltips: QueryList<MatTooltip>;

showAll(): void {
  this.tooltips.forEach(toolTip => toolTip.show())
}
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qdrdajlonpk?file=src/app/tooltip-overview-example.ts)